# Leaving switch in while(1)

Tags: c

I need switch case in while. Every case in the switch is part of the menu which does something. Also I need to handle all the inputs from switch, so default isn't good choice for me. I need to leave while completely when user press CTRL + Z in CMD, where program is happening in order to free memory and quit program. This code is only simplified version of mine. Could you please help me? It's the last thing I need to do to have completed task. Thank you.

```
while (1) {
    scanf("%c", &choose);

    switch (choose) {

    case 1:
        //something
        break;
    case 2:
        // something
        break;

    // no default!

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you actually going to have 256 `case` labels? If not, you are not handling all possible inputs in the `switch` statement, and you should have a `default` case.

Comment: Is this switch refactorable into function? This will always be a cleanest approach.

Comment: `scanf` here will read useless newline bytes, so it's important to do nothing in this case. I guess the program will also ignore all the other unrecognized characters too, so no `default` needed.

Comment: Put a `break` after the `switch` and `continue` inside the `case`s in the `switch` is an option? Or, sometimes using a `goto` makes the code cleaner than a more structured option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows, your program will see that as an end of input file (`stdin`). When `scanf` tries to read a byte from `stdin`, it will fail and return `-1` (`EOF`), while the usual return value is 1 (i.e. number of items read).

So you can use the following code:

```
while (scanf("%c", &choose) == 1)
{
    switch (choose) {

    case 1:
        //something
        break;
    case 2:
        // something
        break;

    // no default!

    }
}
```

I put the return value of `scanf` into the `while`'s condition. When `scanf` cannot read a byte from `stdin` anymore, the loop will terminate.

Comment: wouldn't it be `scanf(" %c", &choose);` ? and choices cannot be 1 or 2 because a char is scanned, not an integer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: If we believe OP’s claim they have to handle all values, then they will handle space, tab, newline, and all other characters.

Comment: It might be possible to press Ctrl+A for `case 1` :)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem in handling control-Z is not leaving the `switch` statement, it is leaving the `while` statement.

On a Windows system, when the user presses control-Z at the start of an input line, the software will act similarly to an end-of-file. Notably, when `scanf("%c", &choose);` executes, there will be no input for it to read, so nothing will be stored in `choose`. Instead, `scanf` will return `EOF` to indicate no match to `"%c"`could be made (because no input was available). However, your code does not test the return value of `scanf`, so it will not see this.  One way to fix this is:

```
while (1)
{
    int n = scanf("%c", choose);
    if (n != 1) // Did scanf match %c and store something in choose?
        break; // No, so break out of the while loop.
    switch (choose)
    …
}
```

Then there is the matter of what should be in the `switch` statement. You say you “need to handle all the inputs from switch.” A `char` typically has 256 possible values. So, unless you have 256 `case` labels in the `switch`, you are not handling all the inputs in the `switch` statement. You should have a `default` label.

If any of the cases inside the `switch` needs to cause execution to leave the `while` statement, you can arrange this in various ways. One way is to use a variable to indicate that:

```
while (1)
{
    int n = scanf("%c", choose);
    if (n != 1) // Did scanf match %c and store something in choose?
        break; // No, so break out of the while loop.

    int LeaveWhile = 0;
    switch (choose)
    {
        case 'A':
            // Code to handle A input.
            break;
        case 'B':
            …
        case something:  // Some case where we want to end the loop.
            LeaveWhile = 1; // Indicate end of loop.
            break;
        …
        default:
            // Code to handle remaining values.
            break;
    }

    // If it is time to leave the while loop, break out of it.
    if (LeaveWhile)
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before describing how I would handle the problem of the "break" keyword being overused in C, there is another issue you may hit that should be mentioned.

The behavior of <kbd>control-C</kbd> and <kbd>control-Z</kbd> vary with the OS and the TTY (console) settings.

Linux, with default TTY settings, will cause an interrupt with <kbd>control-C</kbd>, which if not handled will end the program.  <kbd>control-Z</kbd> will suspend the program.  By default, in neither case is the character delivered to the program, and so it can not be read by scanf, and it will not be dispatched by the switch statement.

Windows will also interrupt with <kbd>control-C</kbd> by default.

I mention this because you depend on reading control characters in your input parsing.  If you aren't having the behavior you want, consider looking at TTY settings.

As for exiting the "while(1)" from inside the switch, the standard way is to change the loop from "while(1){}" to "int looping =1; while (looping){}", and set looping to 0 inside the body of the while loop.

In some cases, I will do this with (cover the eyes of the children watching) a goto to a label after the while body.  I prominently display goto label, and reverse indent it to outside the level of the while loop body.

Sometimes the break condition is more natural, and sometimes the goto is clearer.  If you don't have an aesthetic preference for one over the other, you might default to the break condition rather than the goto.

Comment: The fact that the user interface does something when the user presses control-C other than sending a control-C character to the program does not mean the program cannot receive a control-C character. Commonly, pressing control-V control-C will send a control-C character.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I agree that one can receive a <cntl>-C.  Doing so is not just like receiving most other characters -- either the TTY setting or some other special action is required.  I judged the OP to be relatively new to programming, and may not have been familiar with special character processing in the OS. If I am wrong I apologize to the OP.  I meant no offense.  I was trying to anticipate a next likely problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag at the top of the loop that gets set when you want to break out, then do so after the `switch`:

```
while (1) {
    int breakout = 0;

    scanf("%c", &choose);
    switch (choose) {
    case 1:
        //something
        break;
    case 2:
        // something else
        // exit the loop in this case
        breakout = 1;
        break;
    }
    if (breakout) break;
}
```

Comment: They should also test the return value from `scanf`. If the user presses control-Z (at the start of a line), `scanf` will return `EOF`, and it will not store a value in `choose`.

Comment: The problem is that none of cases is there to close program. Its only for functions of list structure.

Comment: wouldn't it be `scanf(" %c", &choose);` ? and choices cannot be 1 or 2 because a char is scanned, not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

you have also `*do - while*` loop.

```
bool continueLoop = true;

do
{
    switch(something)
    {
        case smth1:
            /* ... */
            break
        case smth2:
            /* ... */
            continueLoop = false;   //whis will exit the loop
            break;
        default
            /* ... */
             break;
    }
}while(continueLoop)
```